# Angular deployment script breaks local repository

Tags: powershell, github, deployment

Whenever I run this code, the first 3 work (and are here for context). After I clear the build folder the PS code copies the files, but it seems to be unable to resolve the folder as being the repository. Github Desktop is telling me that the folder I am looking for does not exist, while all this script does is remove the content of it...

I know its moving them correctly from the build folder to the other and both surely exist, but github desktop is showing me this [image]

Additionally, Would it be possible to generate a commit and push from this command line, so I can redeploy and push in one go without needing to do that manually? (Or should I make a separate post for this?)

```
"build-ghp": "ng build --prod --base-href  https://torbenvanassche.github.io/Portfolio/",
"copy-index": "@powershell Copy-Item ./dist/apps/portfolio/index.html -Destination ./dist/apps/portfolio/404.html",
"copy-build": "@powershell Copy-Item -Path ./dist/apps/portfolio/* -Destination ./../Portfolio/ -recurse -Force",
"clear-build": "@powershell Remove-Item ./../Portfolio/* -Recurse -Force",
"deploy-portfolio": "npm run build-ghp && npm run copy-index && npm run clear-build && npm run copy-build"
```

EDIT: Reiterating my question, how do I delete the contents of a folder, excluding a folder and it content fro the directory in PS Version 5.1?

Comment: Found that I need to have a .git folder but the recurse delete on folders in PS with Remove-Item -exclude doesnt exclude elements inside a folder... `"@powershell Get-ChildItem -Path ./../Portfolio/ -Exclude .git | @powershell Remove-Item"` this is what I found on a different SO post, but its throwing error that the path is an empty array on the Remove-Item...

Comment: What PS code? You didnt include your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line will get all files and folders in a directory one level above the current dir, with the name Portfolio. It will exclude any files or folders with the name ".git". If it doesn't find anything, it will not throw an error. If it finds some, it will recursively remove them, even if they are read-only.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ..\Portfolio -Exclude .git -Force -EA SilentlyContinue | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```